# java memory leak difference between jar and debug

Tags: java, eclipse, memory-leaks, libgdx

Have a confusing issue
I hava java code using the libgdx and bouncyCastle libraries

On the left  Is the code executed  within Eclipse    (Run / Debug)  
On the right Is the code executed  from command line  java -Xms128m -Xmx128m -jar name.jar

Why does the java jar file memory leak running the exact same code any ideas ?

Any ideas how to track down exactly what is causing this ???

Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: How do you know it's a memory leak? Might just be different garbage collectors behaving differently. Does your program actually experience any difficulties?

Comment: The jar fails to run on some hardware.  runs on some but not on others  how can you get the GC to act the same way ?   what causes the differences in the GC behavior ?

Comment: Fails with OOM Error ?

Comment: The short answer is that you have no control over the garbage collector. I recommend doing a google search of "Java garbage collector" for more info. However, if your jar is failing in some cases, I recommend posting an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) as well as the full text of the error.

Comment: PeterMmm, fails/crashes with out of memory yes

Comment: Update                                                                 jconsole shows the memory usage going up and down around 6,000 kbytes  but the Windows Task Manager shows the java.exe process memory constantly increasing until the total system memory used reaches 100%

Comment: The TaskManager is not reliable becuase it shows the native memory allocation of the VM not the heap space the VM uses. Do you also start your app with the -Xmx option on the computer the app is crashing? Is the same JRE Version installed?

Comment: Not sure why the jar fails to run on some hardware, but the fact that memory usage increases when not in debug should not be a problem. It's conceivable that the normal JRE would run the GC less often than the debug JRE in order to increase possible performance.

Answer (score 0):

Try analyzing the heap dump generated on OOM (for HotSpot VM enabled by `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` command-line option - see [B.1.2 -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError Option](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/clopts-139448.html#gbzrr)) with a heap analyzer like [MAT](https://www.eclipse.org/mat/). It'll give you a precise picture on what *really* consumes too much.